# Is there any solution for changing from session to cookie in Jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies, jquery-cookie

I want to change code in this.
change this sessionStorage to cookie in project,

```
sessionStorage.setItem("modelcode", modelcode);
sessionStorage.setItem("setuptypecode", setuptypecode);

var modelcode = sessionStorage.getItem("modelcode");
var setuptypecode = sessionStorage.getItem("setuptypecode");
```

how can I do that?

I try to make function of setCookies and getCookies like below,

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it when ajax complete/success function get call in return after ajax call. In the ajax complete/success you can fetch the set session data and using cookie function you can set it in cookie, but you need to make everything work in ajax complete/success function.

Please let me know if you find any issues

Comment: Is above function setCookie and getCookie is perfect for use or not?

Comment: Yes, it's looks good